# Cohomology over "discrete reals" vs "continuous reals"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, classifying-spaces

The canonical morphism $\mathbb{R}_{\text{discrete}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\text{continuous}}$ of Abelian topological groups
should induce morphisms $B^n\mathbb{R}_\text{discrete} \rightarrow B^n\mathbb{R}_{\text{continuous}}$,
giving rise to a morphism
$$
H^n(X;\mathbb{R}_{\text{continuous}})
\rightarrow
H^n(X;\mathbb{R}_\text{discrete})
$$
natural in "nice" topological spaces $X$, for each integer $n\geq0$;
here we are using the "topological group cohomology" given by $H^n(X;A) = \pi_0\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Top}}(X,B^nA)$
for $A$ a ("nice") Abelian topological group.

If I'm not mistaken, the RHS $H^n(X;\mathbb{R}_{\mathrm{discrete}})$ should coincide with the "ordinary" singular cohomology with coefficients in the Abelian group $\mathbb{R}$.

I was wondering if there is any nice description of the LHS of the above homomorphism, and the homomorphism itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, so are all $B^n\mathbb{R}_{\text{continuous}}$. So $H^n(X;\mathbb{R}_{\text{continuous}}) = 0$ for all $X$.

Comment: Thank you! However I will change the question to be about $\mathbb{Q}$ instead, as this case is less trivial.

Comment: Instead of changing the question to an entirely different question, you should ask a new question instead.

Comment: My mistake, I will revert the question.